# OAuth redirect terminating ASP.NET session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, google-chrome, firefox, oauth

I have an ASP.NET MVC site that is integrating with a third party company.  I'm using OAuth to validate users to the third party company.  Here is the workflow:

- Log in to my application
- Click a button to import data from third party
- User is redirected to the third party authorization page where their credentials are validated (not my application domain)
- Upon successful validation the user must agree to allow my application to access their data stored in the third party database
- Upon agreeing the user is redirected back to my site where I receive a security token from the third party that I use to query their API for the current user's data

What is currently happening in FireFox (and sometimes in Chrome) is when the user agrees to allow my application to access their third party data, the user is redirected to my application's login page.  At that point I've tried to access the internal pages directly but the session is dead.  The interesting thing is if I go through the entire process right away it works.  Of course going through the process twice is not ideal for my customers.  The process works seamlessly in IE.  The production site is hosted on Azure with SSL.

Comment: Depending on Session maybe part of your problem. Try persisting the transient data in your persistence layer (ie. database) across the various redirects. Also, this kind of thing will depend on the OAuth provider (they are not all the same in the details).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard.  I am actually integrating with another third party app and I am NOT seeing the problem with their API.  WIll dig a bit deeper.

Comment: Turns out if you log into a http://sitename.net and then redirect to http://www.sitename.net, FireFox considers them two different sessions.  We were logging into http://sitename.net but the OAuth provider was kicking us back to http://www.sitename.net which bounced us the login page because FireFox somehow determined where we on a different site entirely.  Thanks again fo responding Richard.